# Does the new Database 4.1.0 adapter of GSA don't need connector manager?

Tags: google-search-appliance

Does the new Database 4.1.0 adapter of GSA don't need connector manager?

I tried installing it but I wasn't able to see the instance in the GSA admin console.

I used this --> https://github.com/googlegsa/database/releases/download/v4.1.0/database-install-4.1.0.exe from http://googlegsa.github.io/adaptor/index.html

Is the 4.1.0 adapter administrated from the property file and no UI?

If you have experience with these topics please share your knowledge. Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no connector manager with the 4.x adaptors.  Everything is configured via the configuration file.  If you install using the Windows installer there is a psuedo front end to configuration but configuring with the adaptor.properties file is very easy.

There is a simple UI for confirming the adaptor is running and seeing the active configuration (no edit capabilities).

Comment: Thank you for confirming the understanding. However I wasn't aware of any simple UI that comes along. Thank you for that.

Where can I find it please? Let me explore them. Thank you.

Comment: The adaptor dashboard is on port 5679 by default. You can change this in the adaptor config file.